# Customize SwaggerDocument generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I've written an ASP.NET application that dynamically generates a RESTful web service based on a script. There's a root controller (**/dataserver**) and everything after that depends on the script. The script allows you to specify custom handlers, for example handlers to get data from a database.

Because of this the structure of the api isn't fixed. There's only one controller. I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNet.Core and when it runs it only build a swagger document for that controller. What I'd like to do is intercept the generation of the swagger document so that I can add the structure of the web service into the document.

I've spent some time looking at Swashbuckle but I can't work out how to hook into the document generation so that I can populate. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "structure of the web service"?

Comment: The server reads an xml file that defines the structure of a web service it exposes. The endpoints may to various handlers, so you might have /foo/service1, /x/y/z/service2 etc etc

Comment: Look into IDocumentFilter

Comment: @HelderSepulveda - Thanks. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that the only option I see is to use an `IDocumentFilter` to modify the resulting document.

There are a few examples on the repo:

- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/b64b8fd6fbc7959849445be676f5e3d4a8e947bf/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.Test/Fixtures/Extensions/VendorExtensionsDocumentFilter.cs
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/e2f30e04f412b821a5a989338a186e422c776cc4/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/AnnotationsDocumentFilter.cs
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/b64b8fd6fbc7959849445be676f5e3d4a8e947bf/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/XmlComments/XmlCommentsDocumentFilter.cs

I'm afraid that those examples are too simple for what you are trying to accomplish...
but hopefully, they give you a push in the right direction